# High frequency ionic wind thruster

Tags: electric-current, propulsion

I’ve wanted to build an ionic wind thruster for some time now and thought about ways to increase the thrust density. One thing which came to mind is to use high frequency AC tuned in such a way that when the ions generated from one anode/cathode reaches its opposite the voltage has dropped to 0 and as the voltage increases the ion is pushed away and attracted to the next stage.

Repeat this for multiple stages and you should (in my mind) increase thrust. A square wave would be ideal, however it should probably work with sinusoidal waves too. I’ve done some quick estimations for the maximum frequency needed by assuming acceleration between parallel plated and by assuming that the ions are nitrogen ions (lighter than oxygen ions) and by assuming no collisions. This gives a maximum frequency of around $80$ MHz.

This seems like a totally achievable frequency, and since it’s the maximum the $16$ MHz frequency from an arduino might even work. Now the issue is that I haven’t found any articles or papers about people trying this, which I find suspicious. Does anyone know if this has been tried/if it can work and does anyone have any links to some research on the subject of AC ionic wind?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't my field, but ...

Have you thought of using three of more circuits with steadily increasing separations , e.g.
 1 2  3   1    2     3      1       2        3 
and then switching the attractive polarity through the circuits timed so that the particles are always trying to reach the next attractive ring but never actually reach it before the next polarity switch.

It's be useful for the accelerated particles not to be strongly repulsed by the next electrode when a changeover happens ... You could perhaps try using three or four stages to the cycle, so "+, 0, -, 0, ... ", or "+, 0, 0, +, 0, 0, ..." Perhaps use the master clock to clock some sort of shift register chip?
Or making the electrodes not loops surrounding the thrusterspace, but arcs that sequentially rotate in orientation down the body of the space, so when an attracting electrode flips polarity before an ion reaches it, there's a clear line-of sight slightly to one side to the next attractive electrode in the series. Or a helical arrangement of charge-plates running down the inside of a cylindrical tube?

The closest thing I've seen to this were some of the old flying saucer designs that supposedly used multi-megahertz switching to cycle high-voltage electricity around a sequence of charge/discharge plates. I suspect that how they worked (*if* they worked) was by using electrostatic propulsion to accelerate air around a saucer-shaped lifting surface, the air would then be thrown outward by centrifugal force, hugging the surface and deflecting downwards at the rim because of the [Coandă effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coand%C4%83_effect) . But who knows.

Just wondering aloud. Interesting idea.